# Using jinja2 templates to display json

Tags: python, html, json, flask, jinja2

I have a flask web app set up using jinga2 templates and Json. I'm trying to display the data stored in the json file in my html template. I ideally would like it to display and looks like a list in the html. The page should display the json in a recipe format e.g step my step but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have included my python file, json and html template to help with reproducing the issue.

This is my python file:

```
@app.route('/recipes/pumpkin_pie/')
@app.route('/recipes/halloween/pumpkin_pie/')
def pumpkin_pie():
  recipes = []
  with open('recipes.json', 'r') as f:
     recipes = json.load(f)
     f.close()
  print recipes

  p = {}
  for item in recipes:
     if item['name'] == "pumpkin pie":
       print item
       p = item
       print p

  return render_template('pumpkin_pie.html', pumpkin=p)
```

This is my html tempate file:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="ingredients">
    <p>{{ pumpkin.ingredients }}</p>
</div>
<div class="method">
    <ul>
    {% for result in pumpkin %}
        {% for methods in result %}
            <li>{{pumpkin.methods }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my json file:

```
{
"name": "pumpkin pie",
"ingredients": [" large eggs plus 1 yolk", "1 tsp ground cinnamon"],
"methods": {
    "1": "Pre-heat the oven to 200C/400F/Gas 6",
    "2": "If using a shop bought sweet crust pastry case, use one that is 23cm/9in diameter and 4cm/1.5in deep. If using your own pastry, roll it out and use it to line a 23cm/9in pie plate (not loose bottomed). Bake the pastry case blind for 20 minutes."
} }
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: It displays the json methods like this and shows multiple times  {u'1': u'Pre-heat the oven to 200C/400F/Gas 6', u'2': u'If using a shop bought sweet crust pastry case, use one that is 23cm/9in diameter and 4cm/1.5in deep. If using your own pastry, roll it out and use it to line a 23cm/9in pie plate (not loose bottomed). Bake the pastry case blind for 20 minutes.'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `JSON` file you do not have an array of object. Rather you have only one object. So iterating it assuming as an array of object in Python will not give desire output.

Update the python file as:

```
@app.route('/recipes/pumpkin_pie/')
@app.route('/recipes/halloween/pumpkin_pie/')
def pumpkin_pie():
    recipes = []
    with open('recipes.json', 'r') as f:
        recipes = json.load(f)
        f.close()
    return render_template('pumpkin_pie.html', pumpkin=recipes)
```

And the template file as:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="ingredients">
    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for ingredient in pumpkin.ingredients %}
            <li>{{ ingredient }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="method">
    <h3>Methods</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for key in pumpkin.methods %}
            <li>{{ pumpkin.methods[key] }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

You will get output like:

[image]